# Store Array of Objects to Session Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, cherrypy

I want to Store array of objects to Session in POST request I am getting below error:

Expected string, dict found

```
def POST(self):
    deviceArr1=[{"id":"01","name":"abc"},{"id":"02","name":"abcd"}]
    for device in deviceArr1:
        cherrypy.session['deviceArr'].append(device)
    return cherrypy.session['deviceArr']
```

Also, I want to check if duplicate object is present.

Comment: `List` inside elements can call with `index` not `dict` type. `cherrypy.session` is `dict` but you try append, did you know `session` is allowed list-type or any-type insertions ?

Comment: @dsgdfg No I am new to Python so i need help regarding above case

Comment: So you can't open a_session for edit/change. Locked somewhere, need `unlock` before change somethings(becarefull on data pattern and types).

Comment: did you enable sessions? what is exact error happening? it is vital that you post here full code example which doesn't work for you and any tracebacks/logs you are getting. TIA.